# Ffmpeg in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ffmpeg, cmake, native

i'am trying to add Ffmpeg library to use it in Live Streaming app based in Youtube APi when i add it and i use Cmake Build tool the header files only shown in the c native class which i create and i want it to be included in the other header files
which came with library how can i do it in cmake script or onther way  ?

This my cmake build script

```
# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native
# library. You should either keep the default value or only pass a
# value of 3.4.0 or lower.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds it for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             ffmpeg-jni

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             # Associated headers in the same location as their source
             # file are automatically included.
             src/main/cpp/ffmpeg-jni.c )

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because system libraries are included in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in the
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       ffmpeg-jni

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )

include_directories(src/main/cpp/include/ffmpeglib)

include_directories(src/main/cpp/include/libavcodec)

include_directories(src/main/cpp/include/libavformat)

include_directories(src/main/cpp/include/libavutil)
```

This my native class i create as native file i  android studio and i also have an error in jintJNIcall not found

```
#include <android/log.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>

#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"
#include "libavutil/opt.h"



#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

JNIEXPORT jboolean
JNICALL Java_com_example_venrto_ffmpegtest_Ffmpeg_init(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz,
                                                         jint width, jint height,
                                                         jint audio_sample_rate,
                                                         jstring rtmp_url);
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_venrto_ffmpegtest_Ffmpeg_shutdown(JNIEnv
                                                                            *env,
                                                                            jobject thiz
);
JNIEXPORT jintJNICALL
        Java_com_example_venrto_ffmpegtest_Ffmpeg_encodeVideoFrame(JNIEnv
                                                                     *env,
                                                                     jobject thiz,
                                                                     jbyteArray
                                                                     yuv_image);
JNIEXPORT jint
JNICALL Java_com_example_venrto_ffmpegtest_Ffmpeg_encodeAudioFrame(JNIEnv *env,
                                                                     jobject thiz,
                                                                     jshortArray audio_data,
                                                                     jint length);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#define LOGI(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "ffmpeg-jni", __VA_ARGS__)
#define URL_WRONLY 2
static AVFormatContext *fmt_context;
static AVStream *video_stream;
static AVStream *audio_stream;

static int pts
        = 0;
static int last_audio_pts = 0;

// Buffers for UV format conversion
static unsigned char *u_buf;
static unsigned char *v_buf;

static int enable_audio = 1;
static int64_t audio_samples_written = 0;
static int audio_sample_rate = 0;

// Stupid buffer for audio samples. Not even a proper ring buffer
#define AUDIO_MAX_BUF_SIZE 16384  // 2x what we get from Java
static short audio_buf[AUDIO_MAX_BUF_SIZE];
static int audio_buf_size = 0;

void AudioBuffer_Push(const short *audio, int num_samples) {
    if (audio_buf_size >= AUDIO_MAX_BUF_SIZE - num_samples) {
        LOGI("AUDIO BUFFER OVERFLOW: %i + %i > %i", audio_buf_size, num_samples,
             AUDIO_MAX_BUF_SIZE);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num_samples; i++) {
        audio_buf[audio_buf_size++] = audio[i];
    }
}

int AudioBuffer_Size() { return audio_buf_size; }

short *AudioBuffer_Get() { return audio_buf; }

void AudioBuffer_Pop(int num_samples) {
    if (num_samples > audio_buf_size) {
        LOGI("Audio buffer Pop WTF: %i vs %i", num_samples, audio_buf_size);
        return;
    }
    memmove(audio_buf, audio_buf + num_samples, num_samples * sizeof(short));
    audio_buf_size -= num_samples;
}

void AudioBuffer_Clear() {
    memset(audio_buf, 0, sizeof(audio_buf));
    audio_buf_size = 0;
}

static void log_callback(void *ptr, int level, const char *fmt, va_list vl) {
    char x[2048];
    vsnprintf(x, 2048, fmt, vl);
    LOGI(x);
}

JNIEXPORT jboolean
JNICALL Java_com_example_venrto_ffmpegtest_Ffmpeg_init(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz,
                                                         jint width, jint height,
                                                         jint audio_sample_rate_param,
                                                         jstring rtmp_url) {
    avcodec_register_all();
    av_register_all();
    av_log_set_callback(log_callback);

    fmt_context = avformat_alloc_context();
    AVOutputFormat *ofmt = av_guess_format("flv", NULL, NULL);
    if (ofmt) {
        LOGI("av_guess_format returned %s", ofmt->long_name);
    } else {
        LOGI("av_guess_format fail");
        return JNI_FALSE;
    }

    fmt_context->oformat = ofmt;
    LOGI("creating video stream");
    video_stream = av_new_stream(fmt_context, 0);

    if (enable_audio) {
        LOGI("creating audio stream");
        audio_stream = av_new_stream(fmt_context, 1);
    }

    // Open Video Codec.
    // ======================
    AVCodec *video_codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
    if (!video_codec) {
        LOGI("Did not find the video codec");
        return JNI_FALSE;  // leak!
    } else {
        LOGI("Video codec found!");
    }
    AVCodecContext *video_codec_ctx = video_stream->codec;
    video_codec_ctx->codec_id = video_codec->id;
    video_codec_ctx->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    video_codec_ctx->level = 31;

    video_codec_ctx->width = width;
    video_codec_ctx->height = height;
    video_codec_ctx->pix_fmt = PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    video_codec_ctx->rc_max_rate = 0;
    video_codec_ctx->rc_buffer_size = 0;
    video_codec_ctx->gop_size = 12;
    video_codec_ctx->max_b_frames = 0;
    video_codec_ctx->slices = 8;
    video_codec_ctx->b_frame_strategy = 1;
    video_codec_ctx->coder_type = 0;
    video_codec_ctx->me_cmp = 1;
    video_codec_ctx->me_range = 16;
    video_codec_ctx->qmin = 10;
    video_codec_ctx->qmax = 51;
    video_codec_ctx->keyint_min = 25;
    video_codec_ctx->refs = 3;
    video_codec_ctx->trellis = 0;
    video_codec_ctx->scenechange_threshold = 40;
    video_codec_ctx->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_LOOP_FILTER;
    video_codec_ctx->me_method = ME_HEX;
    video_codec_ctx->me_subpel_quality = 6;
    video_codec_ctx->i_quant_factor = 0.71;
    video_codec_ctx->qcompress = 0.6;
    video_codec_ctx->max_qdiff = 4;
    video_codec_ctx->time_base.den = 10;
    video_codec_ctx->time_base.num = 1;
    video_codec_ctx->bit_rate = 3200 * 1000;
    video_codec_ctx->bit_rate_tolerance = 0;
    video_codec_ctx->flags2 |= 0x00000100;

    fmt_context->bit_rate = 4000 * 1000;

    av_opt_set(video_codec_ctx, "partitions", "i8x8,i4x4,p8x8,b8x8", 0);
    av_opt_set_int(video_codec_ctx, "direct-pred", 1, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(video_codec_ctx, "rc-lookahead", 0, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(video_codec_ctx, "fast-pskip", 1, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(video_codec_ctx, "mixed-refs", 1, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(video_codec_ctx, "8x8dct", 0, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(video_codec_ctx, "weightb", 0, 0);

    if (fmt_context->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
        video_codec_ctx->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

    LOGI("Opening video codec");
    AVDictionary *vopts = NULL;
    av_dict_set(&vopts, "profile", "main", 0);
    //av_dict_set(&vopts, "vprofile", "main", 0);
    av_dict_set(&vopts, "rc-lookahead", 0, 0);
    av_dict_set(&vopts, "tune", "film", 0);
    av_dict_set(&vopts, "preset", "ultrafast", 0);
    av_opt_set(video_codec_ctx->priv_data, "tune", "film", 0);
    av_opt_set(video_codec_ctx->priv_data, "preset", "ultrafast", 0);
    av_opt_set(video_codec_ctx->priv_data, "tune", "film", 0);
    int open_res = avcodec_open2(video_codec_ctx, video_codec, &vopts);
    if (open_res < 0) {
        LOGI("Error opening video codec: %i", open_res);
        return JNI_FALSE;   // leak!
    }

    // Open Audio Codec.
    // ======================

    if (enable_audio) {
        AudioBuffer_Clear();
        audio_sample_rate = audio_sample_rate_param;
        AVCodec *audio_codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_AAC);
        if (!audio_codec) {
            LOGI("Did not find the audio codec");
            return JNI_FALSE;  // leak!
        } else {
            LOGI("Audio codec found!");
        }
        AVCodecContext *audio_codec_ctx = audio_stream->codec;
        audio_codec_ctx->codec_id = audio_codec->id;
        audio_codec_ctx->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO;
        audio_codec_ctx->bit_rate = 128000;
        audio_codec_ctx->bit_rate_tolerance = 16000;
        audio_codec_ctx->channels = 1;
        audio_codec_ctx->profile = FF_PROFILE_AAC_LOW;
        audio_codec_ctx->sample_fmt = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT;
        audio_codec_ctx->sample_rate = 44100;

        LOGI("Opening audio codec");
        AVDictionary *opts = NULL;
        av_dict_set(&opts, "strict", "experimental", 0);
        open_res = avcodec_open2(audio_codec_ctx, audio_codec, &opts);
        LOGI("audio frame size: %i", audio_codec_ctx->frame_size);

        if (open_res < 0) {
            LOGI("Error opening audio codec: %i", open_res);
            return JNI_FALSE;   // leak!
        }
    }

    const jbyte *url = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, rtmp_url, NULL);

    // Point to an output file
    if (!(ofmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        if (avio_open(&fmt_context->pb, url, URL_WRONLY) < 0) {
            LOGI("ERROR: Could not open file %s", url);
            return JNI_FALSE;  // leak!
        }
    }
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, rtmp_url, url);

    LOGI("Writing output header.");
    // Write file header
    if (avformat_write_header(fmt_context, NULL) != 0) {
        LOGI("ERROR: av_write_header failed");
        return JNI_FALSE;
    }

    pts = 0;
    last_audio_pts = 0;
    audio_samples_written = 0;

    // Initialize buffers for UV format conversion
    int frame_size = video_codec_ctx->width * video_codec_ctx->height;
    u_buf = (unsigned char *) av_malloc(frame_size / 4);
    v_buf = (unsigned char *) av_malloc(frame_size / 4);

    LOGI("ffmpeg encoding init done");
    return JNI_TRUE;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_venrto_ffmpegtest_Ffmpeg_shutdown(JNIEnv
                                                     *env,
                                                     jobject thiz
) {
    av_write_trailer(fmt_context);
    avio_close(fmt_context
                       ->pb);
    avcodec_close(video_stream
                          ->codec);
    if (enable_audio) {
        avcodec_close(audio_stream
                              ->codec);
    }
    av_free(fmt_context);
    av_free(u_buf);
    av_free(v_buf);

    fmt_context = NULL;
    u_buf = NULL;
    v_buf = NULL;
}

JNIEXPORT jintJNICALL
Java_com_example_venrto_ffmpegtest_Ffmpeg_encodeVideoFrame(JNIEnv
                                                             *env,
                                                             jobject thiz,
                                                             jbyteArray
                                                             yuv_image) {
    int yuv_length = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, yuv_image);
    unsigned char *yuv_data = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, yuv_image, 0);

    AVCodecContext *video_codec_ctx = video_stream->codec;
//LOGI("Yuv size: %i w: %i h: %i", yuv_length, video_codec_ctx->width, video_codec_ctx->height);

    int frame_size = video_codec_ctx->width * video_codec_ctx->height;

    const unsigned char *uv = yuv_data + frame_size;

// Convert YUV from NV12 to I420. Y channel is the same so we don't touch it,
// we just have to deinterleave UV.
    for (
            int i = 0;
            i < frame_size / 4; i++) {
        v_buf[i] = uv[i * 2];
        u_buf[i] = uv[i * 2 + 1];
    }

    AVFrame source;
    memset(&source, 0, sizeof(AVFrame));
    source.data[0] =
            yuv_data;
    source.data[1] =
            u_buf;
    source.data[2] =
            v_buf;
    source.linesize[0] = video_codec_ctx->
            width;
    source.linesize[1] = video_codec_ctx->width / 2;
    source.linesize[2] = video_codec_ctx->width / 2;

// only for bitrate regulation. irrelevant for sync.
    source.
            pts = pts;
    pts++;

    int out_length = frame_size + (frame_size / 2);
    unsigned char *out = (unsigned char *) av_malloc(out_length);
    int compressed_length = avcodec_encode_video(video_codec_ctx, out, out_length, &source);

    (*env)->
            ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, yuv_image, yuv_data,
                                     0);

// Write to file too
    if (compressed_length > 0) {
        AVPacket pkt;
        av_init_packet(&pkt);
        pkt.
                pts = last_audio_pts;
        if (video_codec_ctx->coded_frame && video_codec_ctx->coded_frame->key_frame) {
            pkt.flags |= 0x0001;
        }
        pkt.
                stream_index = video_stream->index;
        pkt.
                data = out;
        pkt.
                size = compressed_length;
        if (
                av_interleaved_write_frame(fmt_context,
                                           &pkt) != 0) {
            LOGI("Error writing video frame");
        }
    } else {
        LOGI("??? compressed_length <= 0");
    }

    last_audio_pts++;

    av_free(out);
    return
            compressed_length;
}

JNIEXPORT jintJNICALL
Java_com_example_venrto_ffmpegtest_Ffmpeg_encodeAudioFrame(JNIEnv
                                                             *env,
                                                             jobject thiz,
                                                             jshortArray
                                                             audio_data,
                                                             jint length
) {
    if (!enable_audio) {
        return 0;
    }

    short *audio = (*env)->GetShortArrayElements(env, audio_data, 0);
//LOGI("java audio buffer size: %i", length);

    AVCodecContext *audio_codec_ctx = audio_stream->codec;

    unsigned char *out = av_malloc(128000);

    AudioBuffer_Push(audio, length
    );

    int total_compressed = 0;
    while (

            AudioBuffer_Size()

            >= audio_codec_ctx->frame_size) {
        AVPacket pkt;
        av_init_packet(&pkt);

        int compressed_length = avcodec_encode_audio(audio_codec_ctx, out, 128000,
                                                     AudioBuffer_Get());

        total_compressed +=
                compressed_length;
        audio_samples_written += audio_codec_ctx->
                frame_size;

        int new_pts = (audio_samples_written * 1000) / audio_sample_rate;
        if (compressed_length > 0) {
            pkt.
                    size = compressed_length;
            pkt.
                    pts = new_pts;
            last_audio_pts = new_pts;
//LOGI("audio_samples_written: %i  comp_length: %i   pts: %i", (int)audio_samples_written, (int)compressed_length, (int)new_pts);
            pkt.flags |= 0x0001;
            pkt.
                    stream_index = audio_stream->index;
            pkt.
                    data = out;
            if (
                    av_interleaved_write_frame(fmt_context,
                                               &pkt) != 0) {
                LOGI("Error writing audio frame");
            }
        }
        AudioBuffer_Pop(audio_codec_ctx
                                ->frame_size);
    }

    (*env)->
            ReleaseShortArrayElements(env, audio_data, audio,
                                      0);

    av_free(out);
    return
            total_compressed;
}
```

this an example for a header file which i have an error include

```
#include "libavutil/samplefmt.h"
#include "libavutil/avutil.h"
#include "libavutil/cpu.h"
#include "libavutil/dict.h"
#include "libavutil/log.h"
#include "libavutil/pixfmt.h"
#include "libavutil/rational.h"

#include "libavutil/version.h"
```

in the libavcodec/avcodec.h

This code based in this example : 
https://github.com/youtube/yt-watchme

Comment: Please clarify what is wrong with "other header files". You cannot simply drop ffmpeg directories into your cmake build script and expect it to compile the ffmpeg libraries.

Comment: how can i do it ?

Answer (score 1):

1. you miss a space between `jint` and `JNICALL`.
2. you must use the supplied make files to compile the ffmpeg libraries (see [wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Android))

Comment: thank you i solve the jint  JNICAlL can you explain more the second step

Comment: I have added the link to wiki